# Fatal error: Class 'Slim\Views' not found in ...vendor\slim\views\Twig.php

Tags: php, twig, slim

I'm building a simple website in PHP with Slim Framework and Twig template engine.

I've installed Slim and Twig with Composer in the Command Line.

This is my index.php

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Copenhagen');

$app = new Slim\App( array (
    'view' => new Slim\Views\Twig()
));


$view = $app->view();
$view->parserOptions = array(
    'debug' => true
);

$view->parserExtensions = array(
    new \Slim\Views\Twig(),
);

$app->get('/', function() use($app){
    $app->render('about.twig');
});

$app->get('/contact', function() use($app){
    $app->render('contact.twig');
});

$app->run();

?>
```

The error message is:

> Fatal error: Class 'Slim\Views' not found in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\projects\simple-php-website\vendor\slim\views\Twig.php on line 46

It works without the Twig framework. So I guess the trouble is on loading the Twig. I've tried different variations of this line:

`'view' => new Slim\Views\Twig()`

But what confuses me is, that the error message is referring to line 46 in the Twig.php - which is in the core of slim.

I've tried reinstalling Twig and Slim several times.

Any suggestions what is wrong?

Much appreciated!

**EDIT**
This is from my composer.json

```
{
"name": "tyf5vl/simple-php-website",
"authors": [
    {
        "name": "My Name",
        "email": "my@mail.com"
    }
],
"require": {
    "monolog/monolog": "^1.17",
    "slim/slim": "^3.1",
    "twig/twig": "^1.23",
    "slim/views": "^0.1.3"
}
}
```

Comment: You should check out the `slim/twig-view`-package: https://packagist.org/packages/slim/twig-view. It might be easier.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.slimframework.com/docs/features/templates.html
states that ONLY view is this -> composer require slim/twig-view
you should have final file as

```
{
    "require": {
        "slim/slim": "^3.5",
        "slim/twig-view": "^2.1"
    }
}
```